# What is the maximum sustainable population of the earth?

Tags: environmental-impact, ecological-footprint, population

*This question prompted by discussion regarding [this answer](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/6740/3379) to a question about vegetarianism.*

---

I recently came across a U.N. review of studies seeking to determine the earth's maximum sustainable human population: ["One Planet, How Many People? 
A Review of Earth’s Carrying Capacity"](https://na.unep.net/geas/archive/pdfs/geas_jun_12_carrying_capacity.pdf).

The review itself is from 2012, when the world's population was [7.1 billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population_estimates#1950_to_present). The population today is around 7.5 billion. The range of estimates reviewed goes from 2 billion to 1 **trillion(?!)**:

[image: Estimates of Earth's carrying capacity]

Conveniently, most studies put the limit at 8 billion, a number just below the present population.

**In the six years since this review, has a more robust, consensus-driven method been developed to determine the limit? What limit has been determined?**

I'm interested both in the estimate itself, and a discussion of how the methodology used to make the estimate has improved over time.

Answer (score 1):

The largest issue with answering this question is that it depends heavily on other factors, some of which are quite hard to predict. Consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_intensity , which measures how efficient nations are at powering their needs. Consider all environmental impacts (not just energy & climate change), this is a popular formula:

> This formula describes the impact of human activity on the environment as the product of three factors: Population, Affluence, and Technology.
>
> I = P × A × T    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_%3D_PAT

Also notice that even when people or countries become more efficient, that doesn't necessarily reduce damage, since use may then rise:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jevons_paradox

If you made assumptions for all of these factors and their dependencies and interactions, as well as unspecified behaviors (e.g., diet) then one could make a rough estimate of the carrying capacity of the Earth.

Comment: More also in this question [What is the IPAT identity, and does it still matter?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/3142/99)